# Could add_query_arg() redirect user to external site?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I was reading [this](https://yourblogcoach.com/create-a-woocommerce-payment-gateway-plugin/) to learn to create my own WooC payment gateway. It says,

> But if you want the customer to process the payment on the gateway
> website then use the add_query_arg() function instead.

Could I use add_query_arg() to process the payment outside of my site such as `add_query_arg( 'key', 'value', 'http://externalpaymentsite.com' );` by redirecting my user to that site outside of mine?

Answer (score 0):

The function `add_query_arg()` will generate a link with query parameters.

You should also handle the redirect additionally. Something like this will work:

```
$url = add_query_arg('key', 'value', 'http://externalpaymentsite.com');
wp_redirect($url)
exit;
```